# Reviewing new posts

Tags: support

I wonder if I understand how to review new posts. Several items that I "skipped" because I wasn't sure have been cleared. Is that the way it's supposed to work? My interpretation of the label was that I was skipping that post and leaving it in the queue for the next person.

Comment: I'm almost certain that they just go back in the review queue (and are hidden for you only), but I haven't found any source stating this when I looked just now.  Was the question you Skipped [this one](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72511/enterprise-ux-proving-improvement-through-satisfaction-and-quantified-data) or [this one](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72504/users-stating-that-the-redesign-is-too-bright) that I just found in the New Posts queue?

Comment: Yes. I think they were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The skipped question goes back into the review queue for other users. It's just hidden from your own queue. (Source: [@Mayo](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/52195/mayo) and I just tested this out.)

Skipping when you're not sure what to do [is encouraged by the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).